# Copy dependencies with maven

Tags: maven

I want to copy dependencies to target/lib directory.How can i do this by maven?
I tried this:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.aproject.App</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

But it copy libraries inside jar(i want to directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use exactly the same as you posted above, but I'm using version 2.8 of the maven-dependency-plugin. Have you tried updating the plugin dependency?